# Why does the error C3505: "cannot load type library" occur?

Tags: c++, com, 32bit-64bit

I have a compiler error:
"error C3505: cannot load type library".

I have a COM 32/64 bit component, which is successfully compiled with msvc 2012 in both configurations. I also have a test application which loads this COM component during start with the lines:

```
 #define ID_STRING "libid:c734d1af-8cbe-4cae-b501-165099037e41"

 #import ID_STRING version("0.1") no_namespace
```

In the 32bit variant everything works fine. But in 64bit I see the above-mentioned compiler error. It says [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235597.aspx) that the problem is in WOW bitness stuff. I've checked registry. Corresponding type library could be found in both nodes:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{c734d1af-8cbe-4cae-b501-165099037e41}`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{c734d1af-8cbe-4cae-b501-165099037e41}`

So where am I wrong?

UP: I've found a problem. Compile tries to load type library from 32bit dll (only in compilation stage, in runtime program uses 64bit version). So the question is how made compiler use 64bit type library while compilation.

Comment: Stop guessing, use Process Monitor to see if the file is being found and where it is expected to be.

Comment: Thank you. I've looked to procmon log and I found that compiler searches in node `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{C734D1AF-8CBE-4CAE-B501-165099037E40}\0.1\0\win32`, but not `win64` at end (there are both keys).

Comment: Type libraries are *supposed* to be architecture agnostic.  And they usually are, so using the win32 key is not wrong.  If yours is not then the only other thing you can try is using the 64-bit compiler instead of the 32-bit cross-compiler.  Project > Properties > General > VC++ Directories > Executable Directories.  Change $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64) to $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x64).  And of course using the filename instead of the GUID will always work.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you. Everything is clear now.